# Where in the filesystem do I store app's data files?

Tags: blackberry, persistence, filesystems

I need to store some data files for my blackberry app. These are usually small png files that I download and store locally for performance reasons. Also I need to store an xml file locally.

My question is where are these files supposed to be saved on a blackberry? Is there such a thing as an application's home folder or settings folder in the blackberry filesystem?

What would be the path to such a folder?

This is for blackberry os 4.7 or later.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not a huge amount of data (and by the sounds of it, it's not), take a look at the [PersistentStore](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentStore.html) mechanism.  You can store many types of data including native types (String, Integer, etc.) and even byte[] data (for images) using [PersistentContent](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentContent.html).  The nice thing about PersistentStore is that it doesn't require any sort of filesystem access -- it doesn't leave files hanging around -- and if you include a custom class in the persistent store for your app (even a simple subclass of an existing persistible class such as Hashtable), it will automatically delete your persisted data if the app is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

There's no official home folder for your application. In blackberry you can basically read/write just about anything/anywhere (well, you might get a `SecurityException`/`IOException` if you'll try do change some files).
You can write to the SDCard/Internal memory using the paths described [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/File_systems_and_paths_812501_11.jsp).
If you're worried about someone seeing and altering your data there's not much you can do except setting your files and directories as hidden using `FileConnection.setHidden(true)` but this is very lame since they can still be seen even from the native BlackBerry file browser if the user chooses to show hidden files from the menu.

Edit: You could of course encrypt/decrypt your data but this won't prevent someone from deleting it.